# Calculating the sum of polynomials (as another polynomial)

Tags: polynomials, summation

Actually, I wanted to provide a closed-form expression for the summation $\sum_{i=1}^{n} f(i)$

After realizing the complexity/impossibility of this summation, as we can approximate all the real continuous functions to polynomials (as it's noticed in the Stone-Weierstrass theorem), I started to provide a closed-form expression for the summation of polynomials - approximation better than nothing

But unfortunately, I only could do that for degree-1 polynomials:

$\sum_{i=1}^n ai+b = (\sum_{i=1}^{n} ai) + bn = a(\sum_{i=1}^n i) + bn = a(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}) + bn = a(\frac{n^2}{2} + \frac{n}{2}) + bn = \frac{a}{2}n^2 + \frac{a}{2}n + bn = \frac{a}{2}n^2 + (\frac{a}{2} + b)n$

And as we can see, the result is a degree-2 polynomial, $\frac{a}{2}n^2 + (\frac{a}{2} + b)n$

How can I do so, for a degree-m polynomial?

**Edit**

For some reasons, calculating the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n x^i$ would solve my entire question. So, the closed-form expression of this one, is enough for me

Comment: Instead of the power basis $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,\cdots\}$, use the binomial basis $\{1,x,\binom x2=x(x-1)/2,\binom x3=x(x-1)(x-2)/6,\cdots\}$. Note that $\sum_{x=0}^{n-1}\binom xk=\binom n{k+1}$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomials_calculating_sums_of_powers_of_arithmetic_progressions